# MySQL Query to select users opted for only one category

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a table with data similar to below

```
id  UserId  Category
1    5001       A
2    5001       B
3    5002       A
4    5003       B
5    5004       A
6    5001       A
```

1) How do we query table which can fetch me users who have registered only for A category. The user should not be registered for B or any other category.
For the data above, it should return me only

```
3    5002       A
```

2) How do we write a query which can fetch the users who have registered for both A and B category. Not alone A and Not alone B
For the above, it should return me only

```
userId - 5001
```

Can someone help on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution, using `IN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserID, Category
FROM table_name t
WHERE Category = 'A' AND UserID NOT IN (
    SELECT UserID 
    FROM table_name
    WHERE Category <> t.Category
);
```

Another solution using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserID, Category
FROM table_name t
WHERE Category = 'A' AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM table_name 
    WHERE UserID = t.UserID AND Category <> t.Category
);
```

To get the second result, you can use the following solution using a `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.UserId
FROM table_name t INNER JOIN (
    SELECT UserId 
    FROM table_name
    WHERE Category = 'B'
) b ON t.UserId = b.UserId
WHERE t.Category = 'A'
```

Another solution using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserID
FROM table_name t
WHERE Category = 'A' AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM table_name
    WHERE UserID = t.UserID AND Category = 'B'
);
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=da089335c2695384cdf7bb9f34086003)

Comment: Perfect...Thanks a lot